# Select variable by combining string + index in template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object that looks like this

```
public data = {
    column1Code: 63,
    column1Value: "test",

    colum2Code: 85,
    column2Value: "random"
    ...
}
```

I have created a form array with controls for each of these columns

```
<tbody formArrayName="codeSelections">
    <ng-template ngFor let-control [ngForOf]="reportForm.controls.codeSelections.controls" let-i="index">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ "Column" | translate }} {{ i + 1}}</td>
            <td>
                <kendo-dropdownlist [formControlName]="i"
                                    [data]="codeSelectionOptions"
                                    [textField]="'StringValue'"
                                    [valuePrimitive]="true"
                                    [valueField]="'ID'">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</tbody>
```

I was wondering if I can print out variables using the `i` var from the loop.

so for example for eacht column I need to print out a dropdown, this is what I want to achieve, but I can't figure out the correct syntax for it

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [formControlName]="i"
                    [data]="codeSelectionOptions"
                    [textField]="'StringValue'"
                    [(ngModel)]="{{data. + 'column' + i + 'Code'}}"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"
                    [valueField]="'ID'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible, and I can't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Not sure what you try to accomplish. What is `"{{data. + 'column' + i + 'Code'}}"` supposed to do? Is this the value you want to be shown to the user in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

`[]` and `{{}}` are **never** used together in the same attribute or property binding.

```
[(ngModel)]="{{data. + 'column' + i + 'Code'}}"
```

should be

```
[(ngModel)]="data. + 'column' + i + 'Code'"
```

`data. + 'column' is probably not what you want. Use instead

```
[(ngModel)]="data['column'] + i + 'Code'"
```

Expressions can't be used in two-way bindings, therefore you need to split it in value and event binding:

```
[ngModel]="data['column'] + i + 'Code'" (ngModelChange)="updateSelection($event)"
```

(where `updateSelection` as an invented method name you would need to implement) but I actually don't see how it would be useful to use a calculated value for that.

According to the docs http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/forms/

```
[(ngModel)]="data['column']" [textField]="data['column'] + i + 'Code'"
```

might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use angular, but the obvious error is how you're trying to access your object, try this instead

```
{{data['column'+i+'Code']}}
```

I'd also recommend you have an array of objects so that you don't have to have column1code next to column2code ect, you're making life harder for yourself